# Finding the limits of the double integral $\iint dydx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to find the limits of the double integral

> $$\int\limits_a^bf(x)dx=\iint  dydx$$

such that $f(x)$ is a continues function in the domain $[a,b]$

Any hints please?

Comment: $f(x)-f(a_0)=\int_{a_0}^xdf(y)$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\int\limits_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^b \left(\int_0^{f(x)}  dy\right)dx$$

Comment: You can use `\left(` and `\right)` instead of `(` and `)` so that the parentheses are formatted correctly.

Comment: Thanks! Just revised my answer in order to make it  prettier!